# Retaining $_POST generated variable after page refresh

Tags: sql, search, cookies, page-refresh

I'm having trouble retaining my query results when navigating using pagination links.

I've written a code which creates a mysql query based on options that are selected within a search form. Its a self submitting form which uses place the $_POST results in a variable which builds the query here's the code:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST)) {

    $find = array();
    $area = array();

    if (isset($_POST ['location']) && !($_POST ['location'] == "000")) {

        $find [] = $_POST ['location'];         
        $area [] = "location";
    }


    if (isset($_POST ['sector']) && !($_POST ['sector'] == "000")) {

        $find [] = $_POST ['sector']; 
        $area [] = "sector";
    }   

    if (isset($_POST ['hours']) && !($_POST ['hours'] == "000")) {

        $find [] = $_POST ['hours'];    
        $area [] = "hours";
    }   

    while ((list($key1, $val1) = each($find)) && (list($key2, $val2) = each($area))) {
        if ($key1 == 0) {
            $result =  " WHERE " .  strtolower($val2)  . "= " .  "'" . strtolower($val1) .  "'" . " " ;     
        }
        if ($key1 >= 1) {
            $result .=  "AND " . strtolower($val2) . "= " .  "'" . strtolower($val1) .  "'" . " " ;     
        }

    }


}   else {
        $result = NULL ;    
}

?>
```

The problem with this is when I select a one of the pagination links it refreshes the page, which removes the original sql query meaning I just get all of records in the table as opposed to the results based on the search.

So far I've tried using cookies to retain the variable generated by the search form, unsetting the cookie when the user submits another search. This works to some degree, but for some reason after selecting a pagination link 2 times the cookie disappears.

Here's the code I appended to set the cookies, you'll find the edit towards the bottom of the if statement:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST)) {


    $find = array();
    $area = array();

    if (isset($_POST ['location']) && !($_POST ['location'] == "000")) {

        $find [] = $_POST ['location'];         
        $area [] = "location";
    }


    if (isset($_POST ['sector']) && !($_POST ['sector'] == "000")) {

        $find [] = $_POST ['sector']; 
        $area [] = "sector";
    }   

    if (isset($_POST ['hours']) && !($_POST ['hours'] == "000")) {

        $find [] = $_POST ['hours'];    
        $area [] = "hours";
    }   

    while ((list($key1, $val1) = each($find)) && (list($key2, $val2) =      each($area))) {
        if ($key1 == 0) {
            $result =  " WHERE " .  strtolower($val2)  . "= " .  "'" . strtolower($val1) .  "'" . " " ;     
        }
        if ($key1 >= 1) {
            $result .=  "AND " . strtolower($val2) . "= " .  "'" . strtolower($val1) .  "'" . " " ;     
        }

    }

    setcookie("testcookie", "$result", time()-36000);
    setcookie("testcookie", $result);

}   else {
        $result = NULL ;    
}

?>
```

Here's the rest of the corresponding code:

I assigned the cookie to a variable:

$ret_result = str_replace('\', '', $_COOKIE["testcookie"]);

Then performed the query:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posting $ret_result ";
```

I'm also having problems with the query being generated the first time I submit the form. I have to submit the form it twice before the query is assigned to the variable. Which is also the case when attempting to delete the cookie!

I'm at a loss here so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use hidden form fields and store the values you previously received from $_POST[] in them, that way when you 'submit'  by clicking on one of the pagination links, those values would be retained.